# show/hide div based on select value - jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check to see if the value of my dropdown is "Single Date" and then if so, to hide the div #ToDate.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mc-form-field mc-full">
    <label for="formDate">Payment Date:</label>
    <select name="mc-formPaymentDate" id="PaymentDate">
        <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
        <option value="Single Date">Single Date</option>
        <option value="Date Range">Date Range</option>
        <option value="Single Month">Single Month</option>
        <option value="Last 30 Days">Last 30 Days</option>
        <option value="Last 60 Days">Last 60 Days</option>
        <option value="Last 90 Days">Last 90 Days</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="mc-form-field mc-half mc-inline">
    <label for="mc-formFromDate">From Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="formFromDate" id="mc-formFromDate" class="mc-text">
</div>

<div class="mc-form-field mc-half mc-inline mc-right" id="ToDate">
    <label for="mc-formToDate">To Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="formToDate" id="mc-formToDate" class="mc-text">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#PaymentDate").change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'Single Date') {
        $('#ToDate').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: **WOW** can you fix the spacing please?

Comment: Is that all of the JavaScript?  If so, you may want to wrap it in a call to `$(document).ready()` so that it doesn't fire until the DOM is loaded.  Otherwise it might just not see the element to which you're trying to bind.

Comment: Hi David, thanks, I do have it wrapped in a document ready - I just pasted this part of it here.

Answer (score 7):

Try this using jQuery `toggle` method which can take a boolean flag whether to show or hide the element.

```
$("#PaymentDate").change(function() {
   $('#ToDate').toggle(this.value != 'Single Date');
});
```

Comment: That's the first time I've seen `toggle()` take a Boolean argument. Nifty.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, but you need to explicitly `show` the ToDate again if the test is false:

```
$("#PaymentDate").change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'Single Date') {
        $('#ToDate').hide();
    } else {
        $('#ToDate').show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/3F93A/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#PaymentDate").change(function() { 
          if ($(this).val() == 'Single Date') 
               $('#ToDate').hide(); 
      }); 
 });
 </script>
```

Note that I use $(this).val() instead of this.value

Comment: `this.value` is more efficient, but this will still work to hide `#ToDate`.